# Buttons are not spaced with css present

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with buttons in CSS.

Between the first two I get the right distance, but between the second and the third I get two buttons joined (attached) (as in the picture).

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons form {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <form action="createArt.html">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
  </form>
  <input type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="confirmation_edit()" />
  <input type="button" value="DELETE" onclick="confirmation_delete()" />
</div>
```

Comment: You only set a margin on the form (first button)

Comment: You can delete the CSS for `.buttons form` and add `.buttons {gap: 5px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container {
            display: flex;
            //justify-content:space-around;
        }

        .butts, form {
            margin-left: 10px;
            
            
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <form action="createArt.html">
            <input type="submit" value="ADD" >
        </form>

        <input class='butts'type="button" value="EDIT" >

        <input class='butts' type="button" value="DELETE" >
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.buttons form` by `.buttons > *`

`.buttons > * { margin: 0 10px; }`

Comment: Can you please explain this syntax to me? I'm a beginner

Comment: What does > * mean?

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a it's the general child selector. So if you had a 2 divs nested in one div you could use `div > div` to select 1st child, and `div > div > div` to select the 2nd chid.

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a `*` means all elements ~ usually used to set font styles.

Answer (score 0):

You selector is faulty, u have selected 'bottom form, INSTEAD of botto. The later would have selected all the 3 buttons n have applied the CSS rules to all the 3.

Answer (score 0):

As an option it is suitable for small projects, but for a larger project I recommend using classes.
To add styles to an element you can use: element Selector, id Selector, class Selector.
[More information can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons form {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
input:nth-child(2){
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <form action="createArt.html">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
  </form>

  <input type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="confirmation_edit()" />
  <input type="button" value="DELETE" onclick="confirmation_delete()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code dumps are never helpful

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better served with a specific class on the button but here I added the selector the the input based on type (probably not the way to do this; classes should be used to style)

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons form ,
.buttons input[type="button"] {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <form action="createArt.html">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
  </form>
  <input type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="confirmation_edit()" />
  <input type="button" value="DELETE" onclick="confirmation_delete()" />
</div>
```